# Access Function that counts records with specified criteria?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2007 database that has two related tables (let's call them [PARENT] and [CHILD]).  I have created a form that shows the fields of the [PARENT] table and an embedded subform that displays the fields of the related [CHILD] field.

One of the text fields in the [CHILD] table is called "Status".  The status can contain various values (e.g., "Ready", "Waiting", etc.)

I want to create an unbound textbox on this form that displays the number of records in a "Ready" status.  What is the syntax of function that will accomplish that?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to solve my problem via a Function instead of VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub RefreshStatus()
   Dim rs As Recordset
   Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM CHILD WHERE CHILD.Status = 'Ready'", dbOpenSnapshot)
   'tbStatus is your text field on the form
   Me.tbStatus = rs("cnt")
   Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```